# Entity Framework code first setting value of a private setter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model class:

```
public Account()
{

}

public Account(Guid id, int accountnumber, string accountType)
{
    Id = id;
    Accountnumber = accountnumber;
    AccountType = accountType;          
}

public Guid Id { get; private set; }
public int Accountnumber { get; private set; }
public string AccountType { get; private set; }

}
```

And a DbContext class:

```
class BankContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
```

and the main class where I am trying add the values.

```
Account account = new Account();

BankContext bank = new BankContext();
bank.Accounts.Add(new Account(Guid.NewGuid(), 343, "Checkings")
{                 
    Id=Guid.NewGuid();// returns error."Id is not accessible"
});
```

I did good research before I decided to ask help from stackoverflow. I would really appreciate if somebody could guide me on how to add values to the private elements in this scenario.

Comment: so what are you expecting, you are already setting the value via constructor

Comment: I am trying to save it to the database using the entity framework code first. Just assigning to the constructor is not saving my data to the database.

Comment: To save the data into the database you have to call `bank.SaveChanges();`. You are setting the value of `Id` from the constructor to `Guid.NewGuid()`, why do you need to set it again?

Comment: I don't know how but changing the bankcontext class setter to private solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Class public `Guid Id { get; private set; }`.Where Id is private set.
so you can't set the Id value publicly. Means you can't

```
 new Account(...)
{
    Id=Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

It always return "Id is not accessible" error.

Another think why you need to set it. You already set it by using constructor.

```
 bank.Accounts.Add(new Account(Guid.NewGuid(), 343, "Checkings"));
```

It's jest fine.